# Can I somehow know which replacement is taking place from within a callback of preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I'm using **preg_replace_callback** to substitute particular tokens within the string. But apart from actual token I need to know as well whether that token was first, second or third in a subject string. Is there any way to access that info?

I found an argument **$count** in preg_replace_callback definition (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), which counts replacements, but I'm not sure if it is accessible from within callback. Any example of the usage in described context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$count` out variable is only set after all the replacements are done. Instead, try a static variable:

```
function repl($matches) {
    static $count = 0;
    ++$count;
    ...
}
preg_replace_callback('/.../', 'repl', $haystack);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a non-local variable to keep the count.

Comment: Do not like to leave pieces of inner logic outside :) But that was nice too. Amazing how many different solutions exist once you step back from "impossible" task and ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

With php 5.3+ you can also use a [closure](http://docs.php.net/closures) (instead of a global or static variable)

```
$counter = 0
preg_replace_callback('/.../', function($matches) use(&$counter) {
  ++$counter;
  ...
  },  $haystack
);
```

Comment: 5.3 is cool, although vast majority of hosting servers still run lower versions, or even - 4 =-O