# Swap anchor href with img src in php/wordpress

Tags: php, regex, image, wordpress, anchor

I have a wordpress theme which is very image heavy. The images are wrapped in anchor tags that I need to link directly to the file. Here's an example image's markup:

```
<a href="Link_to_attachment_page" ><img src="Direct_link_to_file"></a>
```

What I need is for it to be formatted as follows:

```
 <a href="Direct_link_to_file" rel="shadowbox"><img src="Direct_link_to_file"></a>
```

edit: Accidentally published without finishing writing this.

So far I have a preg_match_all which gets the src for each image on the page and stores it in an array. Like this:

```
preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $content, $m);
```

What I did next was use preg_replace in a loop to change the href of each anchor tag to the corresponding src in the array:

```
for($k = 0; $k <$length; $k++){
   $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<a$1 rel="shadowbox" href="'.$m[1][$k].'"$2$3.$4$5>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   }
```

Now, that successfully sets the href to the value stored in the array. But it sets each href to the same image( the last one).
So that's where I'm stuck. What now?

Comment: You should use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and handle the replacement logic in a function / instead of using a loop. Or use the more inefficient but simpler DOM method, better yet `phpQuery` or `QueryPath` with `qp($html)->find("a img")` etc.

Comment: I thought about this but I don't really think it will help. I need the loop so I can access the src stored within the array. I could be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I'm stating the obvious here, but you know why it sets it to the last in the array? The problem is this line:

```
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Each time you call it in your loop, it replaces ALL your href tags with the current value of $m[1][$k]. So at the end of each iteration of your loop, your href's are ALL set to the image corresponding to that iteration of the loop. Hence why the final result is all containing the image corresponding to the last iteration of your loop.

Possible solutions:

preg_replace has a 'limit' parameter which you could set to 1, to make sure only 1 replacement takes place each time. If you could make it so that your $pattern won't match href's that have already been replaced, then that should solve your problem.

If not, mario's 'preg_replace_callback' solution should work. To see how to check which instance you're replacing within preg_replace_callback, see this question: [Can I somehow know which replacement is taking place from within a callback of preg_replace_callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482493/can-i-somehow-know-which-replacement-is-taking-place-from-within-a-callback-of-p)

Knowing that, you can access the appropriate element in your $m array.

Comment: Ha ha, yeah I did understand why the last image was being displayed, I just wasn't sure where to go from there. The preg_replace limit worked! I should have seen that in the man page earlier but I totally glossed over it apparently. What I wound up doing was setting an attribute as a sort of "flag" on every anchor, then just cycling through them all, searching for only anchors with the flag, and performing the replace only once. Thanks again for your help.